# Inserting css class to parent element

Tags: jquery, css

I tried to insert a class to a parent element. I want to insert a border to parent when the input is checked and is not checked to remove the class.

Thank you

```js
if ($('.input.colorSpanInput').prop("checked")) {
  $('.colorSpan').addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 2px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="colorSpan">
        <input type="radio" name="color" class="colorSpanInput" checked>
  </span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You are selecting all elements with classes `input` and `colorSpanInput`. Remove the . before `input.colorSpanInput` to select the input tag: `$('input.colorSpanInput')`

Comment: did you checked answers? any one worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this, at all. Here's a vanilla Javascript solution for your problem, with comments in the code explaining what's going on.

```js
// get a list of all .colorSpanInput elements in the page
const colorSpanInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.colorSpanInput');

// iterate over the list and add a change listener to each of them
// toggling the selected class on the parent element depending on the checked state
for (const colorSpanInput of colorSpanInputs) {
  // set correct initial state
  colorSpanInput.parentElement.classList[colorSpanInput.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('selected');
  // and add the change listener so things adjust dynamically
  colorSpanInput.addEventListener('change', function() {
    // because checking one radio button will uncheck all others with the same name
    // and because that unchecking won't trigger a change event on those
    // with every change event occurring we need to make sure each radio
    // is evaluated again, otherwise the .selected class never gets removed once on:
    for (const colorSpanInput of colorSpanInputs) {       
      colorSpanInput.parentElement.classList[colorSpanInput.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('selected');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.selected {
  border: 2px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="colorSpan">
  <input type="radio" name="color" class="colorSpanInput" checked />
</span>
<hr />
<span class="colorSpan">
  <input type="radio" name="color" class="colorSpanInput" />
</span>
<hr />
<span class="colorSpan">
  <input type="radio" name="color" class="colorSpanInput" />
</span>
<hr />
<span class="colorSpan">
  <input type="radio" name="color" class="colorSpanInput" />
</span>
```

This will work for any number of `.colorSpanInput` elements, and change only the style of the parent element.